# CakePHP link helper

Tags: php, cakephp

I am currently dabbling a little bit into CakePHP and I was wondering how I can achieve the following link using the HTML->link helper.

Original HTML Link:

```
     <a href="edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon glyphicons circle_plus"><i></i> Edit Client</a>
```

CakePHP:

```
    echo $this->Html->link('Edit Client', ''.$edit_link.'', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-icon glyphicons circle_plus'));
```

Which method can I adapt in order replicate the same exact link structure as in the original HTML link?

Some advise would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your original idea would work; but if it helps, here is a slight modification:

```
echo $this->Html->link(
    '<i></i> Edit Client',
    $edit_link,
    array(
        'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-icon glyphicons circle_plus',
        'escape' => false
    )
);
```

In order to keep HTML tags included in the link text, try using the escape option, like this:

```
'escape' => false
```

*More reference information about the `escape` option (and other options,) can be found [in the CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3alink).*

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the adapted code - indeed my method works just fine with the exception of the "i i's" which I really require to be in there as well. Is there any way to get them included?

Comment: @nickyfsh Ah, I see; are you using the `<i></i>` for something in the button itself?

Comment: Yes - I require it to display the glyphicon in the button.

Comment: @nickyfsh I've updated the answer above to hopefully fit your requirements :)  The important part to note is the `'escape' => false` option near the end of that line of code.  That allows you to include HTML tags without having the tags escaped (and changed into "safer" characters.)

Comment: I've  added the "i /i" before the Edit Client text earlier (as you've done), however it did not work - anyway I've just tested your new method  and it works just absolutely fine! Thank you so much @summea, what a brilliant solution :)